# Getting NameResolutionFailure error

Tags: xamarin.android, httpclient, xamarin.forms

Unable to fetch data in Xamarin.Forms project. I have tried with the following code and is getting **NameResolutionFailure** error.

```
     private const string BaseUrl = "http://intilaqemployees.azurewebsites.net/api/employeesapi";
            public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync()
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                try
                {
                    var jsonResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(BaseUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    //The following line never gets executed
                    var employeesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonResponse);

                    return employeesList;
                }
                catch (AggregateException exception) { }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }

                return null;
            }
```

This is what I have tried so far

1. Have enable INTERNET in android manifest
2. Translating the host name to ip
3. Tried to set host directly by setting client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "intilaqemployees.azurewebsites.net";
4. Putting the wifi off in emulator

Please note: Android emulator does not have any internet connectivity.

Comment: Did you try this in your device?@Shahriar

Comment: Didn't try it on device. @AkashAmin

Comment: Try it there how would you call a service without internet?

Comment: The PC has internet connectivity but not the emulator browser. Since I am debugging the code step by step in VS i think having the internet connection in PC is enough, not sure though.

Comment: No, calling the service will need internet in your device or emulator..

Comment: Have you made sure that the internet related permissions are enabled in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: @Paul: yes, have enable INTERNET in android manifest.

Answer (score 1):

My problem solved by this code:

```
var client = new HttpClient {
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://1.2.3.4"),
    DefaultRequestHeaders = { Host = "example.com" }
};
```